# Filter within groups in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filter

i have a dataset like:

```
 index id col1 col2 col3
 1     1             a    
 2     1             b
 3     1             a
 4     2             a
 5     2             b
 6     2             a
```

I want to filter the database so that I get the first value of duplicates "a" for each group of IDs. The remaining lines can be deleted. For example I should get:

```
index id col1 col2 col3
 1     1             a    
 4     2             a
```

Can this be implemented easily?

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(['id'])` ...

Comment: `df.groupby('id').first()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter only `a` col3, then `groupby` and `first`

```
df[df.col1=='a'].groupby('id').first()

    index   col1    col2    col3
id              
1   1                          a    
2   4                          a
```